# String name including variable

Tags: java, string, random

I have a lot of `String`s, like `l1` or `l23`.
Now I want to print out a random string, e.g. `l3`.

I have already written code for a random number:

```
int r = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((30 - 1) + 1));
```

So, now I want to print a string which's variable name is the letter `l` plus the random integer `r`.

Is this possible?

Comment: You want an array.

Comment: You could do this using reflection but you shouldn't. Use an array instead of separate variables.

Comment: You can use a `Map<String, Integer>`

Comment: What you're suggesting is monstrous. Use an array or [collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an array

```
long[] l = new long[30];

int r = // 1 to 29;
System.out.println("l" + r + ": " + l[r]);
```

Comment: Is it also possible to convert the printed result to a string?

Comment: @lukulus yes, you can print the results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use array. Index can be choosen in random manner:

`System.out.println(l[random.nextInt(30)]);`